# SSH into Google Cloud Platform Virtual Machine not working: Insufficient IAM permissions

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-iam

When I try to SSH into the VM that I created on GCP's Compute Engine, this is the issue that error that is thrown:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) User [X@gmail.com] does not have permission to access user [X@gmail.com:importSshPublicKey] (or it may not exist): Insufficient IAM permissions. The instance belongs to an external organization. You must be granted the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser IAM role on the external organization to configure POSIX account information.
```

I have tried several things, including changing my roles, which you can see here: [IAM Roles that I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mF8g.png)

I have also tried to `add-iam-policy-binding` by running this command:
`gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding --member=X@gmail.com --role=roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser --zone europe-west1-b`. But this results in this issue:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-iam-policy-binding) argument --zone: INSTANCE must be specified.
Usage: gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding (INSTANCE : --zone=ZONE) --member=MEMBER --role=ROLE [optional flags]
  optional flags may be  --help | --zone

For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding --help
```

[This](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux#connect_to_your_instance) has also not proved very useful and neither has [this resource here.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#store-host-key)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can add more relevant information if need be. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To bind a IAM policy for the role compute.osLoginExternalUser for the user X@gmail.com with instance and zone, please run the below mentioned command.

gcloud beta compute instances add-iam-policy-binding your-instance --zone=ZONE --member='user:X@gmail.com' --role='roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser'

For information please follow the article [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/add-iam-policy-binding).

Comment: Thank you, I tried running this. I get this output:
```
ERROR: Policy modification failed. For a binding with condition, run "gcloud alpha iam policies lint-condition" to identify issues in condition.
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.instances.add-iam-policy-binding) HTTPError 400: Role roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser is not supported for this resource.
```

Comment: Checking at the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#external_user), I noticed that the roles/compute.osLoginExternalUser should be assigned at the Organization Level, that is why I was getting the "is not supported for this resource" error message. In order to granting access  from outside of the Organization, please follow the [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/oslogin/manage-oslogin-in-an-org#external-user)

Comment: I figured out the issue a few months ago, the email that was given the privileges was not part of the organisation that created that project. The organisation only granted access to yale.edu emails and I did not have that. I created my own project and it started working. :) Thank you for your help nonetheless